# Is there a simple way to grep a specific letter with sed, grep or anything else?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to run this command:

```sh
grep '&[a-zA-Z]\w*;' -o myfile.html
```

and this is the result:

```
&atilde;
&eacute;
&ccedil;
&atilde;
&eacute;
```

But what I need is this, the first letter after the '&':

```
a
e
c
a
e
```

My objective is replace all these with the first letter after the '&'

Is there any simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Put the first letter in a capture group, then use a back-reference in the replacement.

```
sed 's/&\([a-zA-Z]\)[a-zA-Z]*;/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `gnu-grep` then it is possible using `-P` (PCRE) option:

```
grep -oP '(?<=&)[a-zA-Z](?=\w*;)' file
```

```
a
e
c
a
e
```